# deserializing JSON to .net object

Tags: c#, json

I'm having problems deserializing JSON to objects. I read a couple of answers but none of them helped me.
This is my JSON file :

```
    {
   "meta": {
      "status": 200,
      "msg": "OK"
   },
   "response": {
      "blog": {
         "title": "title",
         "name": "name",
         "url": "url"

      }
   }
}
```

And this is my class :

```
public class TextInfo
    {
        public class Meta
        {
            public int status { get; set; }
            public string msg { get; set; }
        }

        public class Blog
        {
            public string title { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string url { get; set; }

        }

        public class Response
        {
            public Blog blog { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public Meta meta { get; set; }
            public Response response { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Now, I've tried to deserialize the json like so, but i don't know how to manipulate the data :

```
TextInfo txt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TextInfo>(json);
```

Can you help me figure this out ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: *but i don't know how to manipulate the data* What does that mean?

Comment: For example i want to store in a db the Blog name, i don't know how to get that blog name from "txt"

Comment: You mean `textInfo.response.blog.name`? Note you should be using .NET naming conventions, which you aren't currently. Properties should be PascalCase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things:

1. can you provide an error message/log,
2. do you parse just one item or multiple items? In second case: `var txt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TextInfo>>(JSONstr);`
3. Try the following:

   ```
   public class Meta
   {
       public int status { get; set; }
       public string msg { get; set; }
   }

   public class Response
   {
       public Blog blog { get; set; }
   }

   public class Blog
   {
       public string title { get; set; }
       public string name { get; set; }
       public string url { get; set; }

   }

   public class TextInfo
   {
       public Meta meta { get; set; }
       public Response response { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is that TextInfo should contain Meta and Response:

```
public class TextInfo
{
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
    public Response response { get; set; }
}

public class Meta
{
    public int status { get; set; }
    public string msg { get; set; }
}

public class Blog
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public Blog blog { get; set; }
}
```

And you deserialize like you said:

```
TextInfo txt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TextInfo>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `TextInfo` class does not have any properties inside it to deserialize. It only declares another classes.
According to your source, you should deserialize into `RootObject`. This will return you an instance with `meta` and `response` properties.
Then you'll access them:

```
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
Console.WriteLine(obj.meta.msg);
```